# How to fix tkinter TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Button?

Tags: python, json, tkinter, typeerror

```
import json 
from tkinter import *
import os

listai = json.load(open("listai.txt"))
listap = json.load(open("listap.txt"))
dict = {}



def dictAdd(item, value):
     global listai, listap
     print(item) #i did this so i could see where it was getting the error
     print(value)
     if item not in listai:
          dictcreator()
          d = open("dicionario.txt", "w")
          dict[item] = value
          d.write(json.dumps(dict))
          listai.append(item)
          try:
               listap.append(float(value))
          except ValueError:
               listap.append(int(value))
          i = open("listai.txt", "w").write(json.dumps(listai))
          p = open("listap.txt", "w").write(json.dumps(listap))

#dictAdd("cereja", 3.9)



def dictcreator():
     global listai, listap
     for x in range(len(listai)):
          dict[listai[x]] = listap[x]
     d = open("dicionario.txt", "w").write(json.dumps(dict))

#dictcreator()


def Add():
     addtop = Toplevel()
     addtopheight = 300
     addtopwidth = 300
     addentryname = StringVar()
     addentryprice = StringVar()
     xwpos = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - addtopwidth/2)
     ywpos = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenheight()/2 - addtopheight/2)
     addtop.geometry(f"{addtopwidth}x{addtopwidth}+{xwpos}+{ywpos}")
     addtop.resizable(height = 0, width = 0)
     addtop.config(bg="lightgrey")
     addmainlabel = Label(addtop, text="Adicionar alimento novo", font="arial, 19", fg="green", bg="lightgrey").grid(pady=10, padx=8, row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
     addlabeln = Label(addtop, text="Alimento -->", bg="lightgrey", font="arial, 10").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=8)
     addentryn = Entry(addtop, bg="lightgrey", textvariable = addentryname).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=5)
     addlabelp = Label(addtop, text="Preço-->", bg="lightgrey", font="arial, 10").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2, pady=8)
     addentryp = Entry(addtop, bg="lightgrey", textvariable = addentryprice).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=2, pady=5)
     addbutton = Button(addtop, text="Adicionar", font="arial, 10", fg="green", relief=GROOVE, bg="lightgrey", command = lambda: dictAdd(str(addentryname.get()), str(addentryprice.get())))
     addbutton.grid(pady= 20, padx=10, row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
     addtop.mainloop()
def mainwindow():
     global mainwindow
     width = 700
     height = 400
     mainwindow = Tk()
     xwpos = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - width/2)
     ywpos = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenheight()/2 - height/2)
     mainwindow.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{xwpos}+{ywpos}")
     mainwindow.config(bg="lightgrey")
     mainwindow.title("Lista de Compras")
     mainwindow.resizable(height = 0, width = 0)
 
     mainlabel = Label(mainwindow, text="Lista de Compras", fg="grey", width=18, bg="lightgrey", font="arial, 32", justify="right").grid(pady=15, padx = 10, row=0, column=0, columnspan = 4)
     Button(mainwindow, text="Add", fg="green", width=5, command=Add, relief=GROOVE).grid(padx= 20, pady=2, row=0, column=5)

     def edit():
          edittop = Toplevel()
          edittopheight = 200
          edittopwidth = 200
          xwpos = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - edittopwidth/2)
          ywpos = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenheight()/2 - edittopheight/2)
          edittop.geometry(f"{edittopwidth}x{edittopwidth}+{xwpos}+{ywpos}")
          Label(edittop, text="w").grid(row=0, column=0)
          edittop.mainloop
 
 
     for x in range(1, len(listai) + 1):
          listai[x-1] = Label(mainwindow, text=f"{listai[x-1]} --> {listap[x-1]}€", font="18", fg="black", bg="lightgrey", justify="left", width=15).grid(padx = 10, pady = 2, row=x, column=1)
          listai[x-1] = Entry(mainwindow, fg="black", bg="lightgrey", textvariable=f"{listai[x-1]}tv").grid(padx = 5, pady=2, row=x, column=2)
          listai[x-1] = Button(mainwindow, text="Edit", fg="purple", width=5, command=edit, relief=GROOVE).grid(padx= 20, pady=2, row=x, column=4)
          listai[x-1] = Button(mainwindow, text="Eliminate", fg="red", width=7, command=edit, relief=GROOVE).grid(padx= 20, pady=2, row=x, column=5)

          listai[x-1] = Button(mainwindow, text="Eliminate", fg="red", width=7, command=edit, relief=GROOVE)#.grid(padx= 20, pady=2, row=x, column=5)
          listai[x-1] = Button(mainwindow, text="Eliminate", fg="red", width=7, command=edit, relief=GROOVE)#.grid(padx= 20, pady=2, row=x, column=5)

      
     mainwindow.mainloop()

mainwindow()
```

I get the error:

> "TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Button",

when I press the button called "addbutton". If needed here is a little more output of the terminal:

```
laranja
5.7
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/lista de compras/lista de compras.py", line 57, in <lambda>
addbutton = Button(addtop, text="Adicionar", font="arial, 10", fg="green", relief=GROOVE, bg="lightgrey", command = lambda: dictAdd(str(addentryname.get()), str(addentryprice.get())))
  File "c:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/lista de compras/lista de compras.py", line 16, in dictAdd
dictcreator()
  File "c:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/lista de compras/lista de compras.py", line 36, in dictcreator
    d = open("dicionario.txt", "w").write(json.dumps(dict))
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Button
```

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to fix this error :D.
I really appreciate if someone explains to me a way to fix this error.

To better understanding of the code, basically this is a program to add/remove/add shopping cart items, the file "listai.txt" is a array/list of all the food items.
the file "listap.txt" is a array/list of all the prices.
basically what I did was creating a function called dictcreator that creates a dictionary(called "dicionario.txt", which is dictionary but in Portuguese) getting, for example, the item 1 from listai.txt and the price 1 from listap.txt and getting those together.

**EXTERNAL FILES:**

listai: ["cereja","banana","pera","maca","pessego"]

listap: ["1.2", "1.9", "2.3", "3.1", "3.9"]

dicionario: {"cereja": 1.2, "banana": 1.9, "pera": 2.3, "maca": 3.1, "pessego": 3.9}

Comment: The indentation in your code appears broken. starting with `addlabeln = Label(...)`, the indention is unclear. Is that code part of `Add` or is it supposed to be run outside of `Add`.  Until you fix it, we can't run this code. It would also help if your example didn't depend on external files. Please try to write the code to work with some hard-coded data. If for some reason you can't, you need to include an example data file.

Comment: thank you for alerting about that, i didnt even notice that it was badly idented but it is just in here(stackoverflow) because on my code its all right, but again, thanks for letting me know that.By the way, as u said i just added the external files and a lot more of explanation for better understanding of my code.

Comment: We can only see what you post in the question, we can't see code on your personal computer.

Comment: yeye i know sry about that.
but with the information i added now, can u understand why is it giving that error?

Comment: When I run this code (after adding the missing pieces) it works fine. If I type in a string and an integer and click the button, I don't get any errors.

Comment: The problem is when i use the button "addbutton" that its command is "command=lambda: dictAdd(str(addentryname.get()),str(addentryprice.get())) it gives that type error that i refer above
i wish i could sent u a little video with it so u could see

Comment: You need to provide code in your question that reproduces the error. There's nothing in the code _in this question_ that will cause that error. Though, I strongly encourage you to _not_ use `lambda`. Have your button call a function. That will make debugging easier. `lambda` is useful when you must pass an argument, but that's not the case here. Your button can call a function which calls the `get` methods and passes it on to the other function.

Comment: i will try that, thanks for the idea.But i swear it is getting and error when i use the button "addbutton" the one that uses lambda. btw thank you so much for your help.
another thing i notice is when i try to global a stringvar variable it doesent get globalized it even shows an error (im using visual studio code)

Comment: i just tried that and still got the error.
i will get all my code in here so u can see better and run the program without needing to had things

Comment: I think it's impossible for _this code_ to give _this error_. The error shows you're trying to process a Button where you should have something other than a button. This code only creates a single Button, and it's not saved anywhere where it would be accessed by any other code. Please copy and and paste _this exact code_ and tell us if you get the error.

Comment: I updated the code. I copied literally everything from my computer . Try that know and u probably will get the error

Comment: Please examine `dict` right before the line that throws the error, and tell us if it contains what you think it should contain. I'm guessing it doesn't. It definitely doesn't contain what the original code in the question had.

Comment: so, i examinated "dict" and what i did was get a print function inside the dictcreator function inside the for loop and i got this weird output : these are just the first 2 because i can´t fit all it in here but we can understand by just that
what i think it happened is by using "listai[x]" in the mainwindow to create all the button widgets that function(the dictcreator) got those names and threw them in there, im going now try eliminate that parte and see if that works
{<tkinter.Button object .!button5>: 1.2}
{<tkinter.Button object .!button5>: 1.2,<tkinter.Button object .!button9>: 1.9}

Comment: yup it was it, i just tried that and it all worked perfectly
sry about your time spent but thanks again for helping me(this noob over here at python).Really apprecciate
but there is still one weird thing
that is if i didn't globalised those buttons how did they went out the function?
weird

Answer (score 0):

In python, the dictionary key can be any hashable object, while in json it can only be `str, int, float, bool or None`. Try using `dill` or `pickle` to save tkinter objects if you need (which you shouldn't). Hope that's helpful!

Comment: the thing is that before i implemented the lambda function to the button "addbutton" it all worked perfectly without any error.
did i called the lambda function wrongly? or used it in a bad way?